# Is this a known method regarding expressing a prime as the sum of two squares?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that the quadratic $x^2+bx+c$  has integer coefficients and non-zero discriminant and constant term. Then it is a simple exercise for students to prove that the number of positive integer roots of $x^2+bx+c$ added to the number of positive integer roots of $x^2-bx+c$ is either 0 or 2.
This elementary result gives an easy to understand proof of the important theorem of Fermat/Euler concerning sums of squares.

*Theorem*: Any prime $p ≡1 (\text {mod }4)$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares.

*Proof*: Let $p=4K+1$ and consider the finite number of positive integer solutions $(u,v,w)$  of
                                            $$p=(x+y+z)^2-4yz \text{ ①}$$
Any solution $(u,v,v)$  satisfies $p=u(u+4v)$ and so the only solution is $(1,K,K)$. All other solutions occur in pairs, $(u,v,w)$  and $(u,w,v)$, and so there is an odd number of solutions.

Now rewrite ① as $z^2+2(u-v)z+(u+v)^2-p=0$, a quadratic in $z$. Since $p$ is prime, the discriminant $4(p-4uv)$ and constant term $(u+v)^2-p$ are both non-zero. Hence there is an even number of solutions with $u≠v$ and an odd number with $u=v$, for which $p=4u^2+w^2$.

Are proofs similar to this one already known? The closest I can find is  the proof of D. Zagier https://web.archive.org/web/20120205194801/http://www.math.unh.edu/~dvf/532/Zagier.